# ORA-12154 error on Win7 64

Tags: .net, oracle, ora-12154

Is there any solution for this error on Windows 7 64 bit (because I think it's the main cause) in .NET application? (ASP.MVC2 with EF4)

I've:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- Oracle Express 10g (i've tried to install Client 11g, but then, during installation i got another error - Net Configuration Assist~ Error - something about oraclj11 and java)

I've also checked and tried:

- tnsnames.ora - everything is all right
- tnsping  - was successfull
- sqlnet.ora - NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

I'd like to connect with Oracle DB via ASP application (as above) and I still see this error. .NET cannot see alias which is in tnsnames.ora

Comment: I've heard "Oracle sux" war stories before.  This is proof, nobody should have to put up with "something about oraclj11 and java" error messages!

Comment: I updated the tags, might want to check the other ORA-12154 questions

Comment: @Hans Passant: At least Oracle gives (albeit sometimes cryptic) error codes - SQL Server doesn't, no easy reference code to google for...

Comment: @OMG, which leg would you prefer me to pull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error:** ORC-12154 and Oracle Provider not compatible with current OS (povider 32 bit, OS 64)

**OS:** Windows 7 64-bit, .NET 4.0,  Visual Studio 2010, Tunel via SSH (putty)

**Solution:**

1. Uninstall oracle software, especially Oracle’s client (OracleExpress Client and whole db 10g)
2. Install Oracle 11g Client for Windows 7 64-bit. If occurs errors during installation (Config Net Assistant), check and clean previous Oracle’s software. Everything including register and ORACLE_HOME, TNS_ADMIN environment variables should be removed.
3. Install Oracles .NET tools for Visual Studio (it prevents 32 bit and 64 bit’s conflict)
4. Configure TNSNAMES.ORA and SQLNET.ORA

   - tnsnames.ora - check aliast with tnsping  in cmd prompt (tnsping.exe exists in /bin
   - check environment variables: ORACLE_HOME, optional TNS_ADMIN: “ORACLE_HOME/NETWORK/ADMIN”
   - sqlnet.ora variables :

     ```
     NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
     SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)  
     NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN = ORCA
     ```

For me atleast works fine.

Comment: You have killed me. Your post can resume to 'install the latest version', but I was not doing it until you tell me to do it. It finally works, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with the 32-bit Oracle client and the "(x86)" in the long-name file path.  I've got mine to work by using this in a .bat file.

start /B "C:\Progra~2\Microsoft Visual Studio 10\Common7\IDE" "C:\Progra~2\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

Answer (score 0):

One quick easy solution is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567133/very-frustrating-ora-12154-excpetion-finally-resolved

Basically, TOAD.exe, if run from a path containing parentheses, such as:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Quest Software\TOAD\Toad.exe

...will encounter a TNS error when trying to conenct to a database:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Copy the entire Quest Software folder into C:\Program Files and you should be good to go.